# PHP Shuffle Include(ed) Files

Tags: php, arrays, include, shuffle

I'm trying to use SHUFFLE function to show FILE1.php or FILE2.php at random. Here is my code:

```
<?php
$banner1 = include 'file1.php';
$banner2 = include 'file2.php'; 

$banners = array( $banner1, $banner2);

shuffle($banners);

print $banners[0] 
?>
```

The problem I have - if instead of doing ***include 'file1.php';*** i just use text or code, it works fine.

But if I shuffle INCLUDE function, it shows BOTH file1.php and file2.php at the same time.

Please help.

Comment: Try `array_rand()`. Many ways to do this. Just Google "show random files php", and you'll find a whole bunch of answers.

Comment: As an additional comment: "include" is a statement, not a function. It returns false if the file could not be loaded, true otherwise. Nothing you could work on.

Comment: @NaeiKinDus thanks -m I am not a programmer, and don't know the difference ... I'm a layman roofer :) just trying to learn the code.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I will explore this as well. Thanks for suggestion. Cheers!

Comment: @RoofingCalculator A tradesman; right on (same here) ;-) and you're welcome. *We are a rare breed* - Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're including both files when you assign them to the variables.  Include the file chosen from the shuffled array. Try this:

```
$banner1 = 'file1.php';
$banner2 = 'file2.php'; 

$banners = array($banner1, $banner2);

shuffle($banners);

include($banners[0]);
```

Answer (score 4):

When you write `$banner1 = include 'file1.php';`, the file is included.
That's the *call-by-value* strategy. That means that, when you assign a value to a variable, the value is calculated (and here, your files are included).

This is what your script is doing:

```
<?php

// Include file1, and put include's return value in $banner1
$banner1 = include 'file1.php';

// Include file2, and put include's return value in $banner2
$banner2 = include 'file2.php'; 

// Create an array with these return values, shuffle
$banners = array( $banner1, $banner2);
shuffle($banners);

// And print one return value
print $banners[0]
```

That's not what you want. You want to randomly choose a file, and then include it. Your scripts should look like:

```
<?php
$banners = array('file1.php', 'file2.php');
shuffle($banners);
include $banners[0];
```

Then, as Fred-ii said, you could try `array_rand`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php

Answer (score 3):

First you don't want to assign the return value of `include()`, because it will only return false or 1. For more information see the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

And a quote from there:

> Handling Returns: include **returns FALSE** on failure and raises a warning. Successful includes, unless overridden by the included file, **return 1**

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    ob_start();
    require_once("file1.php");
    $banner1 = ob_get_contents();

    ob_clean();

    require_once("file2.php");
    $banner2 = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();


    $banners = [$banner1, $banner2];
    shuffle($banners);
    echo $banners[0];

?>
```

Comment: Loading all the files and keeping them in memory plus using output buffering... I am not sure that it should be the way to go.

Comment: @NaeiKinDus I agree with you, but first I wanted to show OP that he can't save the return value of `include` as he wants and second it should show just an alternative way